# difference between Idle worker thread count and MinThread count in a dump

Tags: asp.net, windbg

Can anyone explain this "**idle**" and "**minLimit**" values. What "**idle**" and "**MinLimit**" means? How are they related?

```
0:000> !threadpool
Work Request in Queue: 4
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 25
--------------------------------------
CPU utilization 0%
--------------------------------------
Worker Thread: Total: 4 Running: 0 Idle: 4 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 200
Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit: 0 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Having not debugged a managed application I did find some posts that explain your question on [tess ferrandez's excellent blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/03/27/561715.aspx) and [another](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2007/03/12/net-hang-case-study-the-gc-loader-lock-deadlock-a-story-of-mixed-mode-dlls.aspx).

So essentially the thread pool will be setup with a min and max number of threads, MaxLimit and MinLimit. From this it has decided in your case that you have 4 threads and it turns out all 4 are idle and not running state. The MinLimit is a hint and does not mean that it will definitely use at least this many threads in the thread pool.